# Importing module in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook

Resolved!
Used this [link](https://anbasile.github.io/programming/2017/06/25/jupyter-venv/) Thanks to all that helped!

Trying to import modules.

I installed anaconda3. I run jupyter through an executable jupyter-notebook.sh. As of now I don't use a venv.

I have tried all of the following methods, including reinstalling anaconda3 and python

1. terminal --> pip install
2. terminal --> pip3 install
3. terminal --> export path to anaconda --> pip install
4. terminal --> export path to anaconda --> pip3 install
5. terminal --> export path to anaconda --> conda install
6. In notebook --> !pip install

But all these methods don't work

Have spent tons of time searching through other stackoverflow tickets but to no avail. Would appreciate any help. Thank you.
[image: problem]

Comment: How do you have installed jupyter? How do you run jupyter? Do you use environnement?

Comment: Updated my description. Thank you for your time

Comment: Thanks for the update, so the excitable,  is it the one that come with anaconda?

Comment: Yes, it is the one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new conda virtual environment using the anaconda prompt.

`conda create -n yourenvironmentname`.

Activate this environment.

`activate yourenvironmentname`

Install the libraries you want and also do a `conda install nb_conda`.

Launch a notebook with `jupyter notebook` in your activate conda environment (ran from the conda prompt).

You can then create a new notebook and choose the newly created environment, you will then be able to import your modules.